# Run Worksheet_Change if multiple defined cells are changes

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that runs a goalseek if the defined named range "N" changes. However, I want the code to run if any of several cells changes. E.g. "N1", "N2", etc..

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False


If Target.Address = Range("N").Address Then

'Goalseek for force equilibrium
Range("Delta_F").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("h_neutral")

End If


Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False


If Target.Address = Range("N, N1, N2").Address Then

'Goalseek for force equilibrium
Range("Delta_F").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("h_neutral")

End If


Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simultaneously? Or one within a range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing your criteria as a `Range` is easier than testing the `Address` as a string.

Building on @Michal's solution, the below will only execute when your changed cell (`Target`) overlaps (`Intersects`) with your 3 ranges (Set as the variable `TargetRange` here). The main difference is the double negative in the test statement which allows you to avoid `Exit Sub` resulting in moderately cleaner code.

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim TargetRange As Range
Set TargetRange = Union(Range("B3"), Range("G19"), Range("N1"))

If Not Intersect(TargetRange, Target) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("Delta_F").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("h_neutral")
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

---

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However, It was poorly described by me. What I need is the code to run, if I change either e.g. N1, or B3, or G19. So if I change cell G19 the code should run, if I change cell N1 the code should run.

And I thought I could just type in all the cell names (that I have defined) into the range, but that does not trigger the code to run (no error message though).

Answer (score 0):

Your condition can be easily checked with `Intersect` function:

```
If Intersect(Range("N"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

If `Target` doesn't lie within your range, it will exit the sub (this condition should be placed as the first command in your `Sub`).

Comment: this is indeed the best code, the answer could be improved by explaining how this works with non-contiguous ranges, specifically in relation to how the OP was testing for simultaneous updates across three ranges versus how this will behave n that same situation.